# Группировка записей в SQL запросе

Tags: запрос, sql

Всем привет. На сайте впервые, поэтому прошу не ругаться, если заполняю не так или ещё чего.

Задача стояла следующая. Есть 2 таблицы (Сериалы и серии). Нужно было вывести серии, группируя в блоки по датам. А если в один день добавлено несколько серий одного сериала, то собственно вместо кучи серий отображать последнюю добавленную в этот день серию. Группировку в блоки по дате я сделал на PHP, но а вот со второй частью справится не могу. В SQL я не силён, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Мне удалось привести запрос к более похожему на рабочий виду, но вместо последней серии, определённого сериала за день, он отдаёт первую. Вот какой запрос получился в итоге:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date( date ) AS date2, date, id, title, flag, category, alt_name FROM dle_post WHERE approve = '1' AND category <>  '11' GROUP BY  date2 DESC, category ASC ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Вот сайт на котором наглядно видно работу скрипта [link text](http://datix.tv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в таком духе?

```
SELECT *
FROM dle_post
WHERE id IN (
    -- Достаем последние (максимальные) ID по датам
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM dle_post
    WHERE approve = 1 AND category != 11
    GROUP BY DATE(date), category
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло!

Answer (score 2):

**upd**

```
SELECT date( dp.date ) AS date2, dp.date, id, title, flag, category, alt_name 
FROM dle_post dp
  join (SELECT date( date ), category, max(id) as id group by date( date ), category) dpd on dpd.id = dp.id
WHERE 
  dp.approve = '1' AND dp.category <>  '11' 
ORDER BY date2 DESC, category ASC, id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Прошу прощения, думал у вас все поля совпадают... По идее запрос должен был вернуть все записи, почему у вас возвращалась одна запись для меня загадка, видимо mysql мне противопоказан.

Comment: Попробовал. Не помогло :(

Comment: id то выберет максимальный, а вот названия и прочее будут первыми. Тут, по-моему, без вложенных селектов не обойтись.

Comment: Выходит что мне нужны именно эти сложные селекты. Если вопрос в оплате, то я готов заплатить

Comment: изменил ответ.